# Am I correclty understand how acquire and realease is work in python lib "threading"

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have this code:

```
class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, counter):
        print("Создание потока" + "\n")
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        print("Присваивание значений" + "\n")
        self.threadID = counter
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
    def run(self):
        print("Starting" + self.name)
        threadLock.acquire()
        print_date(self.name, self.counter)
        threadLock.release()
        print("Exiting" + self.name)
```

And if I understand correctly, all the code between `threadLock.acquire()` and `threadLock.realese()` is unavailable for more than one thread?

Oh, and `threadLock = threading.Lock()`

Is that true or it work in diffrent direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are more or less correct. When `threadLock.acquire` is called, one of two things will happen:

1. If the lock is available, `threadLock.acquire()` will return, and the thread can continue.
2. If the lock is not available, `threadLock.acquire()` will *not* return, and the thread will block.

A thread holding the lock will continue to hold the lock until they call `threadLock.release()`. At that time, if any other thread is blocking on a call to `threadLock.acquire`, *one* of them will be selected to acquire the lock, and its call will finally return.

So yes, if you have two or more instances of `myThread`, only one of them can execute `print_date` at a time.